# iPhone, face-recognition, slide to unlock

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, screen-lock

I am trying to make an app similar to the way you can set a password upon unlocking an iphone.    I have access to face-recognition tech, and I want to make it so that when you slide to unlock you don't have immediate access to the homescreen.  Instead, you"re asked to take a picture of your face, and if it matches then the homescreen unlocks.  I'm aware that any app that changes the slide to unlock or the homescreen features will be rejected, but this one will just present another layer after the slide to unlock.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not unless you planning on releasing it only to the Jailbreak community.

Comment: Not *this* idea again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do that is by developing a jailbreak tweak (and, ofc, you need to jailbreak your device).
There's already a tweak similar to what you are trying to do: RecognizeMe
 [You should check it out.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=u3dUCSvcffU)